# Sending text via whatsapp is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder, whatsapp

I am new to flex mobile app development, I wanna share a text via `whatsapp`. Here is some code.But its not working.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("whatsapp://send?text=Hello how r u???" )
```

Can u please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution found here??

Comment: Nope. After contacting whatsapp team via mail, I came to know that it is not possble, Because whatapp is not providing any 3rd party API. If u got any solution,please comment here @Yossi

Comment: actually I got. Take a look in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Should work perfectly.

```
-(void)whatsapp{
        NSString *massage = [self stringByEncodingString:@"Your massage"];
        NSString *urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",massage];
        NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWhats];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
        } else {
             UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has to have WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
        }
}

-(NSString *)stringByEncodingString:(NSString *)string{
        CFStringRef encodedString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)string, NULL,
                                                                    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        return CFBridgingRelease(encodedString);
}
```